# .NET developer exploring NodeJS, MongoDB, AngularJS and ExpressJS

Tags: c#, asp.net, node.js, angularjs, mongodb

I am a C# .NET developer, and the tools I use to build a web application are:

- SQL Server
- Entity Framework
- .NET Web API
- ASP.NET MVC
- HTML/CSS/jQuery

I have been reading up on AngularJS, NodeJS, MongoDB, and ExpressJS, and it certainly seems like with these "Javascript-ish" technologies, you can build a full blown web application.

My question is where does this leave me with my knowledge of the .NET stack? I want to start embracing these newer technologies, and build my next website with them, however, I am confused as to whether I should completely do away with the .NET stack, or if I should complement these newer technologies with the power of the .NET stack where it might make sense. Here are some of my thoughts:

- MongoDB could replace SQL Server and Entity Framework
- AngularJS can pretty much replace ASP.NET MVC (since both are MVC patterns, having both would be redundant, I think)
- But when it comes to building an API layer, would NodeJS completely replace ASP.NET Web API? or could I use them together? What would make the most sense (generally speaking)? Considering that NoSQL databases like MongoDB have javascript-like syntaxes, do we even need server side APIs?  Couldn't the client (theoretically) directly talk to the DB?
- And where does ExpressJS fit in?

I am hoping someone can help to clarify how these technologies fit in with each other. Pretty sure that a lot of .NET developers looking to explore these newer technologies have the same questions.

Comment: Suggest not needing to learn them all at once, but start with picking up angular. The browser doesn't care where the data comes from but is definitely taking over a lot more of the work that servers traditionally handled. Routing, data processing, html templating etc. You can now build powerful client side apps without even having access to your own server but API's will always be needed